# dashboard-style page with Highcharts graphs

Tags: highcharts

I would like to make something like a dashboard (kinda like the one that you see in many financial site), using Highcharts.

I've got the hang of adding 1 chart to a page, using a container, so I told myself that many containers, duplicating the code for one graph, will do; but I can't get it to work.

I have at least 8 graph, and I would like to organize them either in 2X4 arrangement, or just stacked on top of each other.

Mainly my confusion is coming from the fact that I need a general options section (to group common options), but I also need to customize the graphs, and I need to load data from CSV, so the order in which you do what, is causing me some problems.

I tried to follow an example here, where it was suggested to use setOptions and jQuery.extend, but I was not successful in making it work.

Is there an example that show a skeleton of the webpage, so I can see where to put each function, in which order and what kind of code do I have to put in?

Comment: Each chart would need its own renderTo component. Create another `div` and add another highcharts code block pointing to the new `div`. That is the simplest method.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find example how to add multiple chart like a dashboard: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/sparkline

And copy&paste code:

```
$(function () {
    /**
     * Create a constructor for sparklines that takes some sensible defaults and merges in the individual 
     * chart options. This function is also available from the jQuery plugin as $(element).highcharts('SparkLine').
     */
    Highcharts.SparkLine = function (options, callback) {
        var defaultOptions = {
            chart: {
                renderTo: (options.chart && options.chart.renderTo) || this,
                backgroundColor: null,
                borderWidth: 0,
                type: 'area',
                margin: [2, 0, 2, 0],
                width: 120,
                height: 20,
                style: {
                    overflow: 'visible'
                },
                skipClone: true
            },
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            xAxis: {
                labels: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                title: {
                    text: null
                },
                startOnTick: false,
                endOnTick: false,
                tickPositions: []
            },
            yAxis: {
                endOnTick: false,
                startOnTick: false,
                labels: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                title: {
                    text: null
                },
                tickPositions: [0]
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
            tooltip: {
                backgroundColor: null,
                borderWidth: 0,
                shadow: false,
                useHTML: true,
                hideDelay: 0,
                shared: true,
                padding: 0,
                positioner: function (w, h, point) {
                    return { x: point.plotX - w / 2, y: point.plotY - h};
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    animation: false,
                    lineWidth: 1,
                    shadow: false,
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            lineWidth: 1
                        }
                    },
                    marker: {
                        radius: 1,
                        states: {
                            hover: {
                                radius: 2
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    fillOpacity: 0.25
                },
                column: {
                    negativeColor: '#910000',
                    borderColor: 'silver'
                }
            }
        };
        options = Highcharts.merge(defaultOptions, options);

        return new Highcharts.Chart(options, callback);
    };

    var start = +new Date(),
        $tds = $("td[data-sparkline]"),
        fullLen = $tds.length,
        n = 0;

    // Creating 153 sparkline charts is quite fast in modern browsers, but IE8 and mobile
    // can take some seconds, so we split the input into chunks and apply them in timeouts
    // in order avoid locking up the browser process and allow interaction.
    function doChunk() {
        var time = +new Date(),
            i,
            len = $tds.length;

        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            var $td = $($tds[i]),
                stringdata = $td.data('sparkline'),
                arr = stringdata.split('; '),
                data = $.map(arr[0].split(', '), parseFloat),
                chart = {};

            if (arr[1]) {
                chart.type = arr[1];
            }
            $td.highcharts('SparkLine', {
                series: [{
                    data: data,
                    pointStart: 1
                }],
                tooltip: {
                    headerFormat: '<span style="font-size: 10px">' + $td.parent().find('th').html() + ', Q{point.x}:</span><br/>',
                    pointFormat: '<b>{point.y}.000</b> USD'
                },
                chart: chart
            });

            n++;

            // If the process takes too much time, run a timeout to allow interaction with the browser
            if (new Date() - time > 500) {
                $tds.splice(0, i + 1);
                setTimeout(doChunk, 0);
                break;
            }

            // Print a feedback on the performance
            if (n === fullLen) {
                $('#result').html('Generated ' + fullLen + ' sparklines in ' + (new Date() - start) + ' ms');
            }
        }
    }
    doChunk();

});
```

Comment: Thanks Pawel; altho this is quite complicate (plus I have no clue what sparkline is :) ); but I see the logic in it, and it could be of use for sure.

Comment: A sparkline is a small 'word sized' chart used to give a quick view of changes over time, usually in place of the common trend arrows that are over used and mostly ineffective.  Reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparkline

Answer (score 1):

For a more simplistic start to this problem, take a look at this `example`:

http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/4GaVj/

It's a very simple set up that defines data arrays first (you can do this as part of your CSV parsing), then defines global options via Highcharts.setOptions(), and then defines the individual charts.

There are several different ways to go about this, from this simple example up to more complex, flexible and dynamic approaches.  But if you're looking to start with the basics, this should help.

Comment: Indeed it is simple; btw is there a reason why some write a $.function and everything inside it; versus $(document).ready(function() {} ? I am getting my data from a CSV, so I am trying to figure out where to put my functions, and how you save data in a variable, that will be passed to the series to populate the chart. Ironic that in python it takes me 5 lines to read and parse a text file, while with jquery I am quite lost :) Thanks!

Comment: $(function() { }); is just shorthand for  $(document).ready(function() { });